# Text Mining to Understand if Diagnostics has passed or failed in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to build a diagnostics report to check if diagnostics passed or failed. But i am facing a challenge as employees use different ways of logging results. Example of entries:

1. Diagnostics : Not Pass
2. Diagnostics : Not Fail
3. Diagnostics : Pass
4. Diagnostics: Pass

Some time they insert some other words before result of the diagnostics entered.

How can i make it as flag - to check if the Diagnostics has passed or failed.

Any suggesting would be greatly appreciated in SQL

Comment: why not use some regexp? how many different patterns you have?

Comment: there are close 15 different patterns. What i want to do is to look at where Agent has documented Diagnostics and check with few spaces if Pass or fail is mentioned. I am struggling to get that checked.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could accomplish that would be using PATINDEX and REPLACE.  Without a full listing of the 15 different patterns you mentioned I can't fully evaluate what you're up against, but here's an example.

> [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :  Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a
>   pattern in a specified expression, or zeros if the pattern is not
>   found, on all valid text and character data types.
>
> [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with
>   another string value.

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @Diagnostic TABLE
    (
        [DiagText] NVARCHAR(200)
    );

--Insert some example test data
INSERT INTO @Diagnostic (
                            [DiagText]
                        )
VALUES ( 'Diagnostics : Not Pass' )
     , ( 'Diagnostics : Not Fail' )
     , ( 'Diagnostics : Pass' )
     , ( 'Diagnostics: Pass' )
     , ( 'Diagnostics: Fail' )
     , ( 'SomeOtherText' );

--use a case statement to evaluated the different patterens, along with using replace to take out all spaces.
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%:NotPass%', REPLACE([DiagText], ' ', '')) <> 0 THEN
                0
            WHEN PATINDEX('%:NotFail%', REPLACE([DiagText], ' ', '')) <> 0 THEN
                1
            WHEN PATINDEX('%:Fail%', REPLACE([DiagText], ' ', '')) <> 0 THEN
                0
            WHEN PATINDEX('%:Pass%', REPLACE([DiagText], ' ', '')) <> 0 THEN
                1
       END AS [Passed]
FROM   @Diagnostic
WHERE  PATINDEX('%Diagnostics%', [DiagText]) <> 0;  --This filters for those containing the Diagnoctics verbiage
```